# Swagger UI creating incorrect curl with FileUpload

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui

Using `drf-yasg` I'm generating our Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 docs, but the curl request for a file ulpload field is incorrect.

Here is my view and serializer:

```
class ImportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    raw_data = serializers.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Import
        fields = [
            'raw_data',
            'created_at',
        ]

from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser

class ApiImportView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    POST: Updates an existing obj's data (import)
    """
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    serializer_class = ImportSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some stuff
        file = request.data['file']
        # do some more stuff
        return ApiResponse(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I expect to see a curl like this:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/kapsule/2/import/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "X-CSRFToken: h2BmujsIaV59JFQXgCREcDsZktBxo70myNx9kRQOjWt6BqA6GaPJj3CITzKfocW5" -d @somefile.json
```

note the last parameter is `-d somefile.json`

I actually see:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/kapsule/2/import/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "X-CSRFToken: h2BmujsIaV59JFQXgCREcDsZktBxo70myNx9kRQOjWt6BqA6GaPJj3CITzKfocW5" -d {"raw_data":{}}
```

to be clear the difference is `-d {"raw_data":{}} != -d @somefile.json`.  I am expecting to receive a file object, not json.

How can I tell swagger that this is expected to be a path, or override this behaviour?